# PayPal Sandbox not working, transactions error in dashboard

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am getting the following error in the transactions section of the dashboard (since days, I am not able to test anything):

```
We’re sorry, something went wrong while fetching sandbox transactions. Please try again.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Additionally I cannot create test users ("We’re sorry, something went wrong during account creation. Please try again.") or edit any of the existing users ("Your request is still processing, please wait..."). Seems like my account is completely inactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the PayPal support and it seems to be a global issue at the moment which should be fixed until tomorrow. There is another solution to create a sandbox account right now (see [Unable to use sandbox accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703774/unable-to-use-sandbox-accounts)), but then I am not able to verify those accounts because the notification email with the confirmation link is completely broken. So unfortunately it seems we all just have to wait for it to work again.

Comment: Update: Everything is working again. You may have to create new accounts & apps (my old ones were completely broken & I couldnt use them with the now fixed paypal sandbox).

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue this morning.  I am getting UNKNOWN_ERROR when trying to process via the Sandbox from .NET using SDK as well.  Even the .NET Sample SDK is returning a UNKNOWN_ERROR.  I sure hope they get this fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on the transactions dashboard. Additionally Mass Payout's are not processed, but regular Payment's are working.

Sandbox mode, using Node.js REST API