# Unable to use sandbox accounts

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I really need your help guys. Since two hours I'm facing with a very strange problem related to Paypal Sandbox. I read lot of answers here on stack overflow but none of them helps me.

I'll try the explain my problem: when I create a new sandbox account (respecting all rules like password strength, load balance etc.) I receive the "success" message, the account is created and visible in the list, but when I open it using "Profile" button I receive this error message (and is really a problem because I need to get the username, password and signature to work in sandbox mode):

> Account Details
>
> Your request is still processing, please wait...

No difference between "Buyer" or "Seller" account, it always fail.
I've tried in many ways (using notes, changing email address, using custom numbers into email) but nothing is work for me.

Someone can suggest me what can I do?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found a temporary solution to works with PayPal sandbox.
Instead of create an account using "Create Account" button you have to register a new account using sandbox website.

In details:

- Go To: https://sandbox.paypal.com
- Register a Business Account
- Go To: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/ and click con "Click Here". This link is placed in the Second paragraph of the page:

> Want to link existing Sandbox Account with your developer account? **Click Here** and provide credentials of your sandbox account

You will be redirect to sandbox paypal web site, if you don't do anything it will recognize your previous register account (anyway, if not, you have to login with the new created account), procede with linking process and after you will have, in the list of accounts, a new one with "Profile" button ready to show you informations necessary to works.

I don't understand way paypal release an important tool like this with a lot of bugs. No response received from no one.

BugPal your are luky because we needs you but please, improve your development process! :@

Comment: Did you find a way to verify those accounts? If I open the accounts' notifications the verification email is completely broken (utf8 error & more), so I cannot click/find a verification link.

Comment: @dominikweber no, I've not verified email addresses. I've used a fake credit card added to buyer account and right now I'm able to test my platform. You don't need to provide an email address to validate the account in sandbox mode, Anyway I can see corrupted messages too in the notifications list

Comment: Thanks. I also added a fake credit card - but were you able to execute a payment? Because at that point the transfer gets refused (error 400) and I thought the reason for this was the unverified account.

Comment: @dominikweber I've no problem executing tests. I've used a card type "Discover" and I'm still able to execute sandbox payments. Are you sure that 404 error is not related to your application redirecting to a bad link?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to create a new account & a new app and now it's working.

Comment: @dominikweber I hope that someone from PayPal give as a response and fix this problem. We cannot work in this way.

Comment: @dominikweber news: today I've created new account using the developer panel (buyer account). It works on first test. Something is changed in BugPal?

Comment: Yes, for me everything works now (but I had to create new accounts and a new app).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a general problem on Paypal side. We see same issues with two of our accounts. It was working last friday.

Comment: I don't think this. I've checked the Paypal server status web site, no issues related to sandbox website.